# The dig method does not work correctly with ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-dig

I run `rails c` and write this:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: { bar: { baz: 1 } })
```

And further:

```
params.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

These two lines I took from the page, the link to which is given above.

As a result, I get `nil`.

When working with `Hash` everything is fine. There is a problem when working with `ActionController::Parameters`. I have this problem inside the Rails application.

Need your opinion on this.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `params.dig(*%w[foo bar baz]) => nil` nope :( I tried both strings, and symbols, and combining them...

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code and it returns `1`. What rails version are you using?

Comment: @P.Boro `ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-darwin17]` and `Rails 5.2.2`.

Comment: `params.to_unsafe_h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)`?, wondering the unsafe part.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes! Your option worked! But why does this work this way?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://eileencodes.com/posts/actioncontroller-parameters-now-returns-an-object-instead-of-a-hash/) please, there has been several changes on ActionController::Parameters from Rails 4 to Rails 5.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thank you!

Comment: @SebastianPalma You can write the answer. I will mark it.

Comment: Okay, let me think in a good answer for the `to_unsafe_h` use.

Answer (score 2):

ActionController::Parameters is a subclass of Hash, you can convert it directly to a hash using the to_h method on the params hash.

However to_h only will work with whitelisted params, so you can do something like:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: { bar: { baz: 1 } })
params.permit!
params.to_h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

But if instead you do not want to whitelist then you just need to use the to_unsafe_h method.